# EF Core - map stored procedure result to multiple Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a grouped collection of data (2 levels deep), here's the JSON representation:

```
[
 {
  Year: 2021,
  Houses: [
   {
     HouseName: "Gryffindor",
     Students: [...]
   }
   ...
 ]
}
...
]
```

Years, Houses and Students are separate entities of their own.
I tried using `GroupBy()` and `ToLookup()`, but they are slowing down the response time.

My last futile attempt was something like this:

1. Create a SQL stored procedure that would return flat rows in the following format:

   ```
    <Year, House, StudentId, StudentName, StudentAge>
   ```
2. Create following Entities using code first approach:

   ```
    class YearRow
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<HouseSubRow> Houses { get; set; }
    }

    class HouseSubRow
    {
        public string HouseName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<StudentInnerMostRow> Students { get; set; }

        public int Year { get; set; }
        public virtual YearRow ParentRow { get; set; }  
    }

    class StudentInnerMostRow
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public int StudentAge { get; set; }

        public string HouseName { get; set; }
        public virtual HouseSubRow ParentRow { get; set; }
    }
   ```
3. In `OnModelCreating()` method added the following configurations:

   ```
    modelBuilder.Entity<YearRow>().HasKey(x => x.Year);

    modelBuilder.Entity<HouseSubRow>(entity => {
      entity.HasKey(x => x.HouseName);

      entity.HasOne(x => x.ParentRow)
          .WithMany(x => x.Houses)
          .HasForeignKey(x => x.Year);
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<StudentInnerMostRow>(entity => {
      entity.HasNoKey();

      entity.HasOne(x => x.ParentRow)
          .WithMany(x => x.Students)
          .HasForeignKey(x => x.HouseName);
    });
   ```
4. The output is in this format

   ```
    [
     {
       Year: 2021,
       Houses: [] // empty
     },
     ...
    ]
   ```

The code doesn't throw any compilation or runtime error, it's just not mapping the other entities.

**Expectation**

I was hoping that this flat row

```
<Year, House, StudentId, StudentName, StudentAge>
```

would map to the corresponding entities:

1. Year goes to YearRow
2. House goes to HouseSubRow
3. StudentId, StudentName and StudentAge go to StudentInnerMostRow

**Constraints**

1. Can't use `GroupBy()` or `ToLookup()`. Evaluation shouldn't occur in client side.
2. Can't create any new table in the database, only views and stored procedures are allowed.

Can someone tell me if I was headed towards the right direction?

```
this.dbContext.YearRow.FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC MySproc")
```

Comment: Which version of EF Core are you using? Also `GroupBy` not necessarily is client side operation.

Comment: Also please add your current query.

Comment: Also it seems that you need to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) article.

Comment: I am using EF Core 3.1. The issue with groupBy was that I couldn't use GroupBy inside a GroupBy, EF Core couldn't translate NotMapped properties, anonymous class and also functions such as string.Concat().

Comment: The simplest solution is using a third class for the sp with flat properties and use that class to do your mappings